# MS CRM Custom Workflow to access Project Server web service

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, project-server

I am trying to create a custom workflow in ms crm 4 so that when a task is completed it will take some of the attributes of the task and add an entry in project server on a timesheet. I am able to access the project server web services (PSI) and create a time sheet entry from a c# console app and I can do other custom workflows in crm not related to project server.  When using the Project Server web services (PSI) I have to reference and include 3 office project dll's but I am unsure how to get those registered in CRM when i do the custom workflow plugin registration.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you're either going to have to deploy those DLL's to the Server\bin directory or merge them with your DLL using something like ILMerge and register it all as one big chunk.